# How to build AMI using on-prem template/OVF

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer

We are moving out of market place and planning to use our on-premise image created using ISO+kickstart file for AWS also.
At the moment there are no connectivity from packer server to vmware and hence cannot build an instance . However on-prem template in OVF format is available locally in packer server (and in S3 bucket).

How can packer be used now to convert the local OVF file to AMI ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what packer is, but if you want to create an AMI from an OVF file, you can follow these steps:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html